# Removing a nested key value pair from dictionary based on value in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

The question is one part help one part curiosity, so I have a dict that I'm appending to a list once all my conditions have been iterated through:

```
for col, row in df.iterrows():
    up_list = []

    if row['id_check'] == 'Add all':
    
        l = {'external': {'om': {'id' : row['posm']},
                                    'wd': {'id': row['wdp']},
                                    'wk': {'id': row['tw'].replace('ru: ', '')}
                                    }
                 }

         up_list.append(l)
```

Basically, I'm adding multiple keys and values to the dict l, and my main question is, provided one of values for `'id' == 'None'` I don't want to add the entire key value pair to the dictionary.

So best case output looks like:

```
final_l = {'external': {'om': {'id' : '123'},
                        'wd': {'id': '456'},
                        'wk': {'id': '789'}
                                }}
```

BUT: provided one of those values `== 'None'` based on its corresponding dataframe value, I don't want to replace the 'id' with None, I don't want to have it there at all, so ideally say `'wk' == 'None'` then the output dict would look like:

```
final_l = {'external': {'om': {'id' : '123'},
                        'wd': {'id': '456'}
                                }}
```

But the only thing I can get is:

```
final_l = {'external': {'om': {'id' : '123'},
                        'wd': {'id': '456'},
                        'wk': {'id': 'None'}
                                }}
```

Which is not optimal for my use case. So, How do you delete (or not even add) specific key value pairs from a dictionary based on its corresponding dataframe value? Also if there is a better way of doing this I'm very to open to this, as this "works" but by god is it not elegant.

EDIT Sample Dataframe:

```
   id_check   om    wd    wk
0   Add all  123  None   789
1   Add all  472   628  None
2  Add None  528   874   629
```

Comment: Could you add a sample of the dataframe?

Comment: @MrNobody33 edited the post, sample df under it.

Comment: what it's the other case of `'Add_all'`? I mean, what happen if `row['id_check'] != 'Add all'`? @SebastianGoslin

Comment: @MrNobody33 `Add None` which is a pass over, that specific portion of the dictionary that I'm creating in this loop won't be appended.

Comment: Ready, just added an approach @SebastianGoslin!

Answer (score 1):

I am editing my previous answer both based on your response that you are trying to alter the dictionary and not the dataframe and because my previous answer was incorrect.

I couldn't find a way to do what you are asking using a nice simple way - e.g. list comprehension, but was able to do it with this converter I created:

```
class Converter:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.rows = []
        self.cols = []
    
    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, d):
        conv_df = cls()
        conv_df.cols = list(d.keys())
        conv_df.rows = list(zip(*d.values()))
        return conv_df

    def as_dict(self):
        vals = []
        
        for idx, _ in enumerate(self.cols):
            vals.append([j[idx] for j in self.rows if None not in j])
        return {k: v for k, v in zip(self.cols, vals)
```

Example usage:

```
>>> z = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'c': ['q', 'r', None]}
>>> conv = Converter.from_dict(z)
>>> conv.cols
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> conv.rows
[(1, 'a', 'q'), (2, 'b', 'r'), (3, 'c', None)]
>>> "Get as dict and we expect last row not to appear in it:"
'Get as dict and we expect last row not to appear in it:'
>>> conv.as_dict()
{'a': [1, 2], 'b': ['a', 'b'], 'c': ['q', 'r']}
```

Comment: So the full dataframe has several hundred rows putting the whole thing here is impractical. But if I'm reading what you wrote right, it would be removing all rows that `== None` which in this case wouldn't be optimal since some values can have all the `id`s or some, or none, its varied.

Comment: Right but you could incorporate that into what I am saying. You could have a function that checks for the types and values that you do not want. Then you would have something like `{i: j for i, j in d.items() if not is_wrong_value(j)}`, where `is_wrong_value()` is said function. That is, unless I'm misunderstanding what you mean by "some values can have all the ids or some, or none, its varied".

Comment: Ah I see, so the sample df has one row of all the values that could occur. But in the actual df there is several thousand rows where some may have proper values for each column and some may have None, so it isn't uniform across the whole dataframe. So I'd like to create a dictionary of the format I've made in the question of only the values that occur (are not `None`) in the dataframe.

Comment: I've updated the sample to hopefully make more sense.

Comment: Before your most recent edit, it seemed like you were using the data field in the pd Dataframe constructor to initialize it. I was under the impression the issue was instance creation based - but if you already have a df then I think the best/most pythonic thing to do would be to use the actual api from pandas. That is, `df.dropna`. More info can be found [here](https://thispointer.com/pandas-drop-rows-from-a-dataframe-with-missing-values-or-nan-in-columns/).

Comment: I'm not trying to create/edit a dataframe, I'm using the existing information within the input dataframe to construct a specifically formatted dictionary for ingestion purposes into a database. The input is a dataframe, the output is a dictionary.

Comment: Actually, I see now where I've made a mistake. If you had `d = {'a': [123, 123], 'b': ['abc', 'abc'], 'c': [None, 'q']}` and you did what I told you, you would get a 2x2 df instead of a 1x3, since you would have to drop the entire column `c` because you had one `None` in there. My apologies for the mistake. If I were you I would just drop them after construction using `dropna`.

Comment: That would work but dictionaries don't have a `dropna()` method, thats why i'm asking the question, I'm not trying to filter the dataframe, I'm trying to filter the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you could try with `to_dict`, `dropna`, `eq` and `to_list`:

```
final_l=df[df['id_check'].eq('Add all')].drop('id_check',1)
                         .apply(lambda x : {'external':x.dropna().to_dict()},axis=1)
                         .to_list()
```

Output:

```
final_l
[{'external': {'om': 123.0, 'wk': '789'}},
 {'external': {'om': 472.0, 'wd': '628'}}]
```

Comment: The output still has the keys with 'None' in them sadly (unless it was a typo), so for your `final_l[0]` the desired output would be `{'external': {'om': 123.0, 'wk': '789'}}` and `final_l[1]` `{'external': {'om': 472.0, 'wd': '628'}}`, I'm trying to remove the key's that are `None` from appearing in the dict.

Comment: Please, see the update @SebastianGoslin it was helpful?

Answer (score 0):

So I tried the provided answers, and the biggest issue I ran into was truth evaluation and speed. I coded this which "works" but I'm not too happy with it from an efficiency standpoint:

```
if row['id_check'] == 'Add all IDs':
        
        link_d, ex_link = {}, {}
        if row['posm'] != 'None':
            link_d['om'] = {'id': row['posm']}
        if row['pd'] != 'None':
            link_d['wd'] = {'id': row['pd']}
        if row['tw'] != 'None':
            link_d['wk'] = {'id': row['tw']}
            
        ex_link['external'] = link_d
        up_list.append(ex_link)
    
    up_d[row['id']] = up_list
    all_list.append(up_d)
```

Which outputs:

```
{'external': {'om': {'id' : '123'},
                     'wd': {'id': '456'},
                     'wk': {'id': '789'}}}
```

and ignores keys where the value == `None`:

```
{'external': {'om': {'id' : '123'},
                     'wd': {'id': '456'}}}
```